# Presentation with many fullscreen video

Tags: openoffice.org, vlc, presentation, software-recommendation, libreoffice

I am currently creating a presentation (like power point). I have tried multiple applications to create this presentation but there are some problems.

I have tried

- Ease: Program is not stable crashes randomly
- OpenOffice: Works fine but video flickers in the beginning and don't pause in the end.

Thanks

Comment: What's the format of the video you use?

Comment: I create the video in Blender. Currently I'm using H264

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have previously done a presentation with VLC and a WiiMote.

VLC can display JPEG and PNG images as well. To pause after an item (especially images) add "vlc://pause:9999" below it in the playlist editor.

Information about getting a WiiMote to work can be found here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CWiiD 
It's a bit tedious, but not as hard as it may look.

The main draw of this approach is that VLC itself does not have any layout features, so that would have to be done in GIMP, Draw or similar.
In any case: good luck!

Comment: Sounds interesting more details please

Comment: Would love to hear if and how it works out for you.

Comment: It worked perfectly. I have got a A+ Grade :-)

Answer (score 0):

The question has been answered and accepted, but for what it's worth, here's one for the record.

I am a big fan of [Prezi](http://www.prezi.com). If you're looking for stability, intra- and inter-OS compatibility and multimedia capabilities (not to mention cool transitions and a non-linear presentation style), it's a good solution. The downside is that the offline version is paid and only available for Windows and Mac; if you want to use it on Linux and/or keep it free you'll need a computer with internet connection and updated Flash Player (check [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/430786/wireless-presenter-with-prezi) for problems you may encounter using Flash Player 11.2 or lower).