# VLC 1.1.5 can't view PNG images

Tags: vlc

If I want to view a PNG file in the VLC Player I get the error message:

> Kein passendes Decodierungsmodul: VLC
>   unterstützt das Audio- oder
>   Videoformat "Kein passendes
>   Decodierungsmodul: VLC unterstützt das
>   Audio- oder Videoformat "undf" nicht.
>   Leider können Sie daran nichts ändern.
>   " nicht. Leider können Sie daran
>   nichts ändern.

Comment: Your question is not clear based on your later comments, are you trying to produce a video from PNG images ?

Comment: No I actually want to crate a powerpoint like presentation using the vlc player (this presentation contains videos and still images). More infos: http://askubuntu.com/questions/15012/presentation-with-many-fullscreen-video/15013#15013

Answer (score 6):

That error is complaining that VLC doesn't have a codec for decoding PNGs... And why should it? PNGs are images. It's a bit like asking VLC to open a .doc file.

VLC doesn't have code for decoding PNGs because that's not what it's for. PNGs aren't supported.

If you want them to be, ask at [VideoLan.org](http://www.videolan.org) but I doubt they really want to invest time implementing something they think other applications should handle.

Comment: Well I have tried to convert the PNG file to an AVI with this command : 'ffmpeg -b 1024k -r 1 -i img.png img.avi'    but the image looses quality

Comment: Please take a look on this answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/15012/presentation-with-many-fullscreen-video/15013#15013