# Wireless Presenter with Prezi

Tags: wireless, flash, presentation

I have a [Targus Wireless Presenter with laser pointer](http://targus.com/US/wireless-presenter-with-laser-pointer-amp16us) which I intend to use with my [Prezi](http://www.prezi.com) presentations. The presenter works perfectly when presentations are not maximized, but when they are, the frame-flipping buttons do not work. I've tried this with both Chromium and Firefox and the behavior is the same. The presenter works okay in LibreOffice Impress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this page](https://prezi.zendesk.com/entries/22413761-Presenting-with-remote-clickers), you need to have Flash Player 11.3 or higher in order to have wireless presenters work with Prezi on fullscreen.

Unfortunately, support for Flash Player for Linux stopped just before that, and if you use Firefox or Chromium you're stuck at version 11.2. One easy way to work around this is by installing Google Chrome. Unlike Chromium or Firefox, Chrome comes with its own, up-to-date Flash Player (currently, version 12).

Google Chrome is not available in the Ubuntu Software Center, so you'll need to get it somewhere else. I recommend the official website: https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/

Answer (score 2):

I installed the browser Chromium from the Ubuntu software center. Then I had to update Flash and restart Chromium. Finally the presenter worked with prezi :-)